# How to implement search query to filter on search key is equal to title?

Tags: search

I have changed the search query from the search page. I would like to filter on ContentType X. This is working. I have created a new result source which is get only items from ContentType X. Now I would like to add an extra filter that the search key needs to be equal to the Title column of each items. I have now something like this but it dont work. What do I forget?

```
Title: {SearchBoxQuery}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the Query does not work? You are using a contains query, is that what you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is Title={SearchBoxQuery}